# How can I pipe in a string to a Raku program?

Tags: pipe, program-entry-point, signature, raku

`foo.raku`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env raku
use v6.d;

sub MAIN (Str $some-text = $*IN.slurp, Bool :$verbose) {
    say "Your text:" if $verbose;
    say $some-text;
}
```

When I run it

```
~% echo "Hello World" | ./foo.raku --verbose
```

I get:

```
Your text:
```

How do I write the Signature in `MAIN` so that it captures piped-in strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: you currently can not.

I think https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#$*ARGFILES tells the reason in a roundabout way.

I see two ways around this:

Make the first positional optional without a default, and check for definedness later

```
sub MAIN (Str $some-text?, Bool :$verbose) {
    say "Your text:" if $verbose;
    say $some-text // $*IN.slurp;
}
```

Grab the contents of `$*IN` **before** `MAIN` gets executed, and use that as the default:

```
my $default = $*IN.slurp;
sub MAIN (Str $some-text = $default, Bool :$verbose) {
    say "Your text:" if $verbose;
    say $some-text;
}
```

In any case, using `$*IN.slurp` has its disadvantages if the script is called *without* being piped some input.  It will just wait for the user to type in something without prompt.  Which could be interpreted as hanging.  So you probably want to add a check using https://docs.raku.org/routine/t#(IO::Handle)_method_t somehow, if at least to provide some visual feedback:

```
say "Type input, then ^D" if $*IN.t;
my $default = $*IN.slurp;
sub MAIN (Str $some-text = $default, Bool :$verbose) {
    say "Your text:" if $verbose;
    say $some-text;
}
```

Comment: The first solution did the trick!  Thank you.

What's odd is that when I remove the :$verbose flag (from my original code), the program runs as expected, both with an argument or with piped-in text.